# Does whatsapp sharing link read meta tags of restricted route?

Tags: javascript, php, meta-tags, whatsapp, sharing

I have a detail page for article. This page has all meta tags in head section needed for sharing that article on whatsapp like an object on Facebook. But this detail page route is allowed after login. This route is restricted before login. Will whatsapp read meta tags for that route if that route is not allowed?

I am facing this issue because when i allow that route, Meta tags are read fine but when i restrict that route before login or unauthorized user then it does not read meta tags?

What is reason, I can not understanding it properly.

Comment: Probably because the `<meta>` tags on that route is rendered dynamically (or the page is rerouted if the user is not logged in): it contains the proper tags if the user is logged in, but not when user is not. If you want whatsapp to have access to the meta tags of a logged in user, you will need to provide it upfront even when the user is not logged in.

Comment: meta tags are rendered dynamically according to specific article title, image, description from controller's action and that action is only called when user is logged in

Comment: Maybe you can detect the user agent of the whatsapp crawler, and display the relevant meta tags to that useragent

Comment: But what if for some article it shows image and description and for some it does not ? Even google and twitter shows image and description for same article fine.

Comment: Are you sure Facebook / Google doesn't show a cached version of that page? Because you didn't provide any technical details I don't think we can know for sure how "they" manage to crawl your website pages, while whatsapp can't

Comment: Honestly speaking, Twitter and google is finding out proper image and description but whatsapp can't.

Comment: Best way is to check your page on the opengraph checker: http://opengraphcheck.com/

Comment: @Terry this link does not show any meta tags but sharing is working fine for google and twitter

Comment: Can you share the meta tags in one of the pages just as an example? There is insufficient information here to diagnose your issue.

Comment: @Alon Eitan thanx for suggestion. Detected user agent and finally its working.